# Using MongoDB in AWS Lambda with the mLab API

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mlab

Usually you cant use MongoDB in Lambdas because Lambda functions are stateless and operations on MongoDB require a connection, thus you suffer a large performance hit in setting up a DB connection each time a function is run.

A solution I have thought of is to use mLab's REST API (http://docs.mlab.com/data-api/), that way I dont need to open a new connection each time my Lambda function is called.

On problem I can see if that mLab's REST service could become a bottleneck, plus im relying on it never going down.

Thoughts?

Comment: How often is your function being called?  If it is being called often enough you can set up the connection outside of the handler to have it persist between multiple executions.  This is an approach I have taken in the past for apis that require a connection, but is not valid in all use cases

Answer (score 3):

I have a couple of alternative suggestions for you on this. Only because I've never used mLab.

- Setup http://restheart.org/ and have that sit between your lambda micro services and your MongoDB instance. I've used this with pretty decent success on another project. It does come with the downside of now having an EC2 instance to maintain. However, setting up restheart is pretty easy and the crew maintaining it and giving support is pretty great.
- You can setup a lambda function that pays the cost of connecting and keeping a connection open. All of your other microservices can then call that lambda function for the data they need. If it is hit more frequently, you will not have to pay the cost of the DB connection as frequently. However, that first connection can be pretty brutal so you may need something keeping it warm. You will also have the potential issue of connections never getting properly closed, and eventually running out.

Those two options aside, if mlab is hosting your DB, you already have put a lot of faith in their ability to keep a system alive. If they cant keep an API up that lack of faith should also translate to their ability to keep your DB alive.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for that. You are right about trusting the DB. Tho the REST API docs say they strongly recommend not relying on it so *shrug*. I am thinking of trying out documentdb, its got a REST API built in.

Comment: Depending on how complex your application is, if its just using CRUD operations by ID, you could try using S3. Wrote a little NPM module to help out with that as its something I've started to do with more regularity on things I write. S3 is incredibly resilient and the performance is surprisingly reliable. Combine that with some of the other features within S3, versioning, cross region replication and fronting a bucket with cloud front it can be pretty compelling.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-db